# custom widget including both theme n plugin?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

Looking forward adding page attributes to woocommerce product page as my website WordPress picks up default sidebar or custom sidebar of responsive theme. so how can I have custom widget on product page which includes woocommerce widgets n not default page widgets of theme.[image: check image]

[image: see image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install [WooSidebars plugin by Woothemes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woosidebars/)
- In Admin panel, go to Appearance/Widget Areas, then create your custom widgets.

Comment: No woocommerce product page doesn't appear.it do display theme pages.

Comment: it should work. check their document for more detail. Make [https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woosidebars-2/](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woosidebars-2/)

Comment: Make sure you selected the sidebar you want to replace. Clicked on Advanced button with the gear icon, then select the page name "Products". The result: http://imgur.com/a/TbaV6

Comment: Yes that worked. ...DO important lesson always check all links :)

Comment: How can i have custom sidebars or widget for woocommerce products as we have it for theme pages.I have woo sidebars woocommerce plugin widget ligic and responsive theme

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Any image or demo thing?

Comment: See on responsive theme page we have sidebar options to choose which type to keep content/sidebar content/nosidebar but nothing like that on woocommerce product page

Comment: It eating up my days☺

Comment: Kindly check image which explains well

Comment: The sidebar you are talking is meta box. It depends on your need, so I couldn't explain more.

Comment: Yes how to get that on product page

Comment: May these link will help you:

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190335/woocommerce-change-template-for-single-product-page,

Comment: Yes custom template on product page

Comment: another way is working with hook, check here https://wpthememakeover.com/2016/03/07/how-to-customize-the-woocommerce-single-product-page/.

Comment: No it's not working .even got same response from people on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check image which explains well